# What should we do about [tablename]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Although it (probably) doesn't pass the burninate test, it's also generally not a useful tag to apply to questions. The [tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablename)tag has 140 questions but no usage guidance or tag wiki. They're about SQL table names mostly, but what exactly users are doing with table names isn't exactly clear.

Sometimes they're [changing all the table names in a Google Sheet integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958875/8954291) and sometimes they're [using dynamic tablenames in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67266524/8954291). The unifying condition is that they're most definitely working with table names.

Looking at the related tags, most of them are SQL-related, but there's also [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions which are using `table` in a different sense. Many questions use [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) and [tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablename) to indicate that they're passing table names to a function.

What do you say?

Comment: Definitely fails the sniff test at least; I don't imagine there are any experts in "table names".

Comment: sounds to me like it passes the burninate test

Comment: IMH(APW)O, not every tag has to define an univocal category or topic: some of them can be "context-dependent" tags. In other words, it's OK to have a tag like [tag:resources] which requires a second, context tag to narrow the type/usage of resources we're talking about. The alternative would be to create single tags for every possible combination: sql-tablenames, excel-tablenames, sas-tablenames, dynamic-sql-tablenames etc. which would be a tremendous waste of resources (sorry, I mean waste of disk-resources, tag-resources, cpu-resources, memory-resources and human-resources ;)

Comment: @walen That's assuming it's useful to tag a question with a [tablenames] tag in the first place. Do you foresee any value in finding questions based on that tag or topic? I don't, personally. What could tablenames refer to. Probably the most common questions there are "what should I name my table" or "does it matter what my table is named" which are both bad types of questions.

Comment: @TylerH The kind of on-topic questions I'd expect to find with such a tag would deal mainly with table name length errors (e.g. github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11801 or asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::p11_question_id:3109217869403) or dynamic table names (e.g. docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/515768/table-name-as-a-variable.html or dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143512, or stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725, which arguably would benefit more from having a `tablenames` tag than from having 3 overlapping `sql*` tags).

Comment: @TylerH Anyways, the point of my comment was not so much "`tablenames` is a good tag" as it was "a given tag not mapping to a single specific topic is not a sufficient reason to conclude it is a bad tag". The `tablenames` tag might be a bad tag indeed, but not for that reason _only_.

Comment: While [tag:tablenames] might not be the most useful tag, I would say it doesn't do any harm and should just be left alone for the moment. Many question appear to be on topic, and relevant to the tag itself. It also generally does point in the correct direction for the topic, similar to [tag:list], even if it's not clear on it's own.

Comment: @walen Actually a tag not mapping to a single topic _is_ typically evidence of a bad tag; we have a whole [tag:tag-disambiguation] process for such tags here on Meta.

Comment: @MegaIng [tag:list] is a bit different, not least of which because it's several orders of magnitude more-used, but also because it refers, at least some of the time, to a first-class data type in many programming languages.

Comment: @walen Regarding your examples, only of those is a Stack Overflow question, and that one doesn't have the tablenames tag but _does have 8 answers and over 130k views. I don't think it's suffering from lack of ideal tags. In fact even the least-used, least-watched tag on that question, [tag:dynamicquery], has three times as many watches and more than 2x as many uses as [tag:tablenames], so changing it would actually be *harmful* to that question, not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I just looked through all 140 questions with the tag. Some concerns about relevant things the tag might be used for in the comments above included table name length errors or dynamic table names. The data below indicates those are not, in fact, typical uses of the tag. Dynamic table name questions *all* also use the [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) tag, but there is actually a [dynamic-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-tables) tag that has ~240 uses already that should be used instead of [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic)[tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablename).

| Type of Question | Number of Questions |
| --- | --- |
| Dynamic Table Names | 10 |
| Table Name Length | 1 |
| Generic ("do something with/based on table name") | 104 |
| Unrelated to Table Names, or entirely off-topic | 25 |

Many of these are also close-worthy for various reasons (not reproducible, needs detail, needs an MRE, etc.).

Based on the ambiguous/vague nature of the tag, the quality of the questions, and on the empirical data above, my recommendation is to clean up this set of questions: close questions that need closing, edit the questions that need editing, and remove the tag from questions that aren't really about table names or that have another relevant tag already (like [dynamic-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-tables)).

At that point we're left with a better/smaller set of questions to consider if it should be burninated or not.

Comment: Now _these_ are good reasons to claim this is a bad tag.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR - I think we should burn it.**

---

Here's the criteria for burnination:

### 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Not really: *"table name"* isn't (in my opinion) a great description of a question. And, [as TylerH showed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420273/18746959), it's definitely not unambiguous.

### 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Ok, it fails this test, but it passes the other ones.

### 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Saying that your question is about *"table names"* doesn't help anyone. Instead, tag it with something like [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) or [dynamic-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-tables)

### 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. As seen in TylerH's answer, there is a wide range of interpretations of this tag.

Also, another point is that no one is going to specialise in [tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablename). Given all this, I think it passes the burnination test, so we should burn it.

---

P.S. There are also [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) and [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) tags. If we burn [tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablename), I think we should burn them as well.

Comment: Note that tags are not designed to be "descriptions of questions"; they are designed to provide meta categorizations that relate to what the question asks.

Comment: Regarding [tag:columnname] and [tag:rowname], decisions on those should be made in different discussions, since they are different, unrelated tags.